# Laravel Broadcast - Disconnect previously authorized user

Tags: php, laravel

Let's suppose I have a private broadcast channel and I decide to authorise a particular user. What if I decide to revoke the authorisation for that user at some point? How can I disconnect that user from my broadcast channel?

Answer (score 0):

To leave a channel, you may call the leaveChannel method on your Echo instance:

```
Echo.leaveChannel('channel');
```

Comment: It's not an answer, because it's client side. I need to revoke the authorisation on server side.

Comment: Could you plz show us what you tried so we could look

Comment: @Bob this is an answer, just not what you want

Comment: @AndySong you should not trust the client side, because it's out of your control.

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI I want to revoke the authorisation to listen to a channel. This answer is like: "client, can you please stop listen to a channel?".